# RoR: why doesn't rake db:migrate output anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-migration

I added add_column :microposts, :type, :string to one of my db migrations (not the most recent one if that matters). and also ran rake db:reset. So I have definitely made changes. But now if I run rake db:migrate or bundle exec rake db:migrate, it doesn't output anything. If I run trace...

```
alex@alex-ThinkPad-T410:~/rails_projects/final2$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

> I added add_column :microposts, :type, :string to one of my db
>   migrations (not the most recent one if that matters).

This suspiciously sounds, as if you just added the text into the migration file. That won't work. The migration state machine doesnt notice changes in the actual text files. Please check

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

You should instead create a new migration

```
rails g migration AddTypeToMicropost type:string
```

and then run rake again